# Installing Add ons

Tags: add-on

I have been trying to install the Building tools and the MB Labs add ons.  I have followed all instructions.  When I click to install them, they show up as having been installed.  But, when I hit "N" to bring them up in properties, they are not there.
Am I missing a step?  or have others had a similar problem.  If so, what is the solution?

Comment: Have you enabled them in *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons* (checkbox ticked in front of the add-on's name)?

Comment: Sometimes, addon after being installed and activated require Blender to be restarted.